# which web server would you suggest me to use IIS 8.5 Apache server Nginx for PHP

Tags: php, apache, iis, nginx, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a production server running on windows 2012 r2.
Which web server would you suggest me to use
**IIS 8.5**,
**Apache server**, or 
**Nginx** ?
(install separately)
I'm PHP developer (so, my code is written in PHP)

Comment: What sort of services will you be running on the host?

Comment: semi - heavyweight php application intagrated with SAP, db in mysql.
of course with Memcached. In the fututre i'm planning use Redis in project

Comment: Is SAP involved with this application at all?

Comment: No, just in some pages i'm passing data from sap to php

Comment: I think in that case you'll have to look at what exactly you want from the webserver, and see which one offers that.  Nginx is fast and memory efficient, but apache has more mature support for PHP.  You should also look at expected server load.  Unfortunately I can't say much about IIS, since I've hardly ever used it (except, from what I remember, it's a pain to set up and customize).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was used to Apache 2 and didn't use anything else. But sinds I'm using Laravel, which supports HHVM, I use Nginx in combination with HHVM. The sites running on that server have more than 40% faster response time. 
If you don't use Laravel, I don't know if your project fully supports HHVM, if so i really would consider using it!

Comment: I've used codeigniter to build app, and i'm not using HHVM. i know Nginx+HHVM is faster in some tasks.
What do you think? - to install Apache(or NGINX) + PHP + MySql separately or use WAMPP or XAMPP or OpenServer?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with Nginx or Apache

Comment: What do you think? - to install Apache(or NGINX) + PHP + MySql separately or use WAMPP or XAMPP or OpenServer?

Comment: Would suggest to with Apache + PHP + Mysql separately.